# Can't bind 2 objects from JSON in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I'm new to Angularjs. I am learning about factory. 
In my example, I have 2 requests to Restful Api and got 2 responses in JSON format.

With the first json, I can use ng-repeat to show them but the 2nd json can't bind to the view.

How can I bind both responses into the same view?

this is my code

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='f1feed'>
  <head>

    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
          padding-top: 10px;
          background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DriverController">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">Drivers Champion Standings</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Full name</th>
                    <th>Driver ID</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody  ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$index + 1}} </td>
                    <td>{{driver.Driver.givenName}} {{driver.Driver.familyName}}</td>
                    <td>{{driver.Driver.driverId}}</td>
                    <td>{{driver.points}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="info">
            <h1>1st Driver Detail info</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Driver ID: {{alonso.driverId}} </li>
                <li>Date of Birth: {{alonso.dateOfBirth}} </li>
                <li>Nationality: {{alonso.nationality}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

file app.js

```
var app = angular.module('f1feed',[]);
app.factory('DriverSev', function($http){
    var driverApi = {};
    driverApi.getDriverStands = function(){
        return $http({
            method: 'JSONP',
            url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
        });
    };
    driverApi.getDetail = function(){
        return $http({
            method: 'JSONP',
            url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/alonso.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
        });
    };
    return driverApi;
});
app.controller('DriverController', function DriverController($scope, DriverSev){
    $scope.drivers = [];
    $scope.alonso = [];
    DriverSev.getDriverStands().success(function(data){
        $scope.drivers = data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
    })
    DriverSev.getDetail().success(function(data){
        $scope.alonso = data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers;
        console.log($scope.alonso);
    })
});
```

Thanks

Comment: do you need to put them (2 JSON) in the same list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$scope.alonso` is unused in your view put it in another ng-repeat to display it

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Drivers Champion Standings</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  ng-repeat="alon in alonso">
            <tr>
                <td>{{$index + 1}} </td>
                <td>{{alon}}</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

if it's the same data model, push it in `$scope.drivers`

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.alonso` is an array.

```
        <ANY ng-repeat="details in alonso">
            <any>Driver ID: {{details.driverId}} </any>
            <any>Date of Birth: {{details.dateOfBirth}} </any>
            <any>Nationality: {{details.nationality}}</any>
        </ANY>
```

should do the trick, or something ugly such as `{{alonso[0].driverId}}`

Comment: Thank you. It works. I almost forgot to use another ng-repeat in this case.